# How create notification after 3 days in ten o'clock?

Tags: process-builder, contact, tasks, notification

I created process builder, but notification after 3 days, but I need afrer 3 days in ten 0'clock!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined immediate action, you need to define the scheduled action.
[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=0) is a documentation which should help you with that.

> When a record-change process executes a field-based schedule, Salesforce uses the field’s current value. If the value is a date/time field, Salesforce uses the time zone of the user who created the process. If the value is a date field, Salesforce uses the org’s time zone.

You can create a new datetime field on the record and as an immediate action use formula to set this field for the desired day and time. Then schedule action to execute 0 days after this field.

Comment: But I need to create after 3 days in 10 o'clock! In Scheduled action only after 3 days(

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you))))))